# KCF Tracker in OpenCv 3.1.0 - no output, no error reported

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I followed the suggestions in

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/640

to fix the bug, but still didn't get anything.

Essentially KCF doesn't initialize, and no errors are reported. If anyone managed to get KCF running in opencv for Python, would be great to know. all other trackers work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. I edited the sample code given on https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/. First select the rectangle around the object you want to track and press Enter.

```
import cv2
import sys

(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

# Set up tracker.
# Instead of MIL, you can also use

tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN']
tracker_type = tracker_types[2]

if int(minor_ver) < 3:
    tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)
else:
    if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
    if tracker_type == 'MIL':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
    if tracker_type == 'KCF':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
    if tracker_type == 'TLD':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
    if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
    if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
        tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ok, frame = cap.read()

#Initializing a bounding box 
bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

while(1):
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);
    if ok:
        p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
        p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
    else :
        # Tracking failure
        cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)
    cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);

    # Display FPS on frame
    cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);

    # Display result
    cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

    K = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if (K==27):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You need to install opencv-contrib libraries for this code to work. To install opencv-contrib, open command prompt and type "pip install opencv-contrib-python" provide you have pip installer on your system